# D3: Can I get better performance when drawing and redrawing a series of rects?

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, d3.js

I've created a linear heatmap with d3 by binding rectangles to my data (time and value):

[image: heatmaps]

Each heatmap can contain hundreds (in some cases thousands) of `<rect>` elements. The browser draws them initially without issue, but as I move along my timeline using a d3 axis (zoom behavior and programatic redraws), I see huge performance issues in my transition (a known SVG drawback).

Is there any way I can combat this? Would using a `<linearGradient>` with an equal number of `<stop>` elements improve things? Do I need to go with canvas instead of SVG?

Thanks!

Comment: How'd you end up settling on this? Did you use canvas?

Answer (score 2):

A linearGradient likely wouldn't help as you'd still need a DOM element for each stop. Canvas sounds like the way to go.